# ObjC: find if number is present in collection

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsnumber, nsset

I have a list of long values:

```
300210, 300211, 310210, 310211, ...
```

I'm looking for the best way to check whether a number is present in a collection. The collection is non mutable and this check can possibly happen hundreds of time per second (it's part of a physics engine collision presolving).

If using an NSArray, I'm to use NSNumbers. These are objects - Is the containsObject: method using hashcodes? Or does it consistently use a value comparison (rather than pointer address)?

How about NSSet? I know it has a member: method to use isEqual: but no practical experience with it.

thanks for your help find the best way to address this.

Comment: If you want it to be fast then using Objective-C collections looks like a mistake, given it can only store objects.

Comment: Interresting point @trojanfoe, I'll go that way :-)

Comment: OK then.  Now you might want to think about how to optimize this search (which is very expensive for a large number of objects) by organizing them in something other than a flat array.

Comment: Yes it uses hash codes. If NSSet is too heavy, CFSet might work... You'll have to compare the performance of std::set with CFSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest turn on objective-C++ and use std::set. It's much faster then `NSSet`.
You will need:

in header:

```
#include <set>
using namespace std;
```

in code:

```
set<int> numberCollection;
```

Comment: Hmm I'd never have thought about that... sounds like the best solution given my situation :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `NSArray`, if the array contains `NSNumber` then you can use  `containsObject:`
as they match with the value not with the pointers.

```
NSNumber *num3 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:3];
NSArray *array = @[@1, @2, num3, @4, @5];

BOOL isExists = [array containsObject:@3]; // yes
```

Also with `NSSet` you can do similar way:

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:array];

BOOL isExists = [set containsObject:@3];
```

Comment: thanks, this clarifies the equality checks. Your comment also taught me about NSNumber shorthands :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can read a great article about Objective-C collections and their performance at [objc.ico](http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html).

In your case (checking if a collection contains given object) the NSSet is definitely the best choice.

> NSSet and its mutable variant NSMutableSet are an unordered collection of objects. Checking for existence is usually an O(1) operation, making this much faster for this use case than NSArray.